# Error in inserting a string parameter to a cypher query in a java code

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to insert a string parameter to a cypher query in Java. Below is the code I used and I have a person node named 'piyumi' and I want to make relationship with an activity node. The name of the activity node is 'walking'. When I execute the code I get http status code 400. Can anyone help me to modify the cypher query so that I can insert the string variable s without error.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class NeoAPIClass {
    private final String baseUri = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher";
    private final String user = "neo4j";
    private final String password = "12345";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
            NeoAPIClass n=new NeoAPIClass();
            n.runQuery();
    }

    void runQuery() throws JSONException {
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user, password));
        WebResource cypherResource = client.resource(baseUri);


        String s="walking";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("query", "Match(piyumi : Person{name:\"Piyumi\"}) create (piyumi)-[:doing{timestamp:4789}]->(n:activity) WHERE n.name=s");
        String st = obj.toString();

        ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypherResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).entity(st).post(ClientResponse.class);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... "+ cypherResponse.getStatus());


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to combine the `create` and `where`. You need first match person and activity, and then create a relationship.

And also recommend to simplify the transfer parameters in a separate part of the request (https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-use-parameters):

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
JSONObject params =  new JSONObject();

String query =  "MATCH (P:Person { name:{personName} }) \n";
query = query + "MATCH (A:activity { name:{activityName} }) \n";
query = query + "CREATE (P)-[rel:doing { timestamp:{activityTimestamp} }]->(A) \n";
query = query + "RETURN P, A, rel";

request.put("query", query);

params.put("personName", "Piyumi");
params.put("activityName", "walking");
params.put("activityTimestamp", 4789);

request.put("params", params);

ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypherResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .entity(request.toString())
            .post(ClientResponse.class);

System.out.println("Response: " + cypherResponse.getEntity(String.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the cypher server can't see the variable `s` from your Java code.  You need to pass a cypher query that has the `String` itself, rather than the name of a Java variable.

You could change the line with `obj.put` to this.

```
obj.put("query", "Match(piyumi : Person{name:\"Piyumi\"}) create (piyumi)-[:doing{timestamp:4789}]->(n:activity) WHERE n.name=\"" + s + "\"");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I replaced the obj.out line with the line you have given. But I still get the same error. can you please help me further with this issue.

Comment: Well, that error shows that the cypher server can't make sense of the query that you've provided.  I'm not sure why, because I'm not particularly familiar with the cypher query language.  Does the cypher server produce any logs that might have a more helpful error in them?

Comment: Then I don't know how to help you.  You'd need someone who knows cypher really well to look at  your query.  The problem is with the query itself, not the Java program.  Sorry that I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs when you try to retrieve existing node. 
So, go to http://localhost:7474/browser/ and execute below query,

MATCH (n:activity)
WHERE n.name="walking"
CREATE (piyumi:Person{name:"Piyumi"}) - [r1:doing{timestamp:4789}]-> (n)

If it works fine, then retrieve it.
MATCH (piyumi:Person)-[r1:doing]->(n:activity) 
RETURN r1

So your query code should looks like this,

`"MATCH (n:activity)\nWHERE n.name=\"walking\"\nCREATE (piyumi:Person{name:\"Piyumi\"}) - [r1:doing{timestamp:4789}]-> (n)"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. But I need a variable name instead \"walking\" there. Can you help me with this. I want to put s there.

Comment: If this is correct, then you could just construct it by writing `"MATCH (n:activity)\nWHERE n.name=\"" + s + "\"\nCREATE (piyumi:Person{name:\"Piyumi\"}) - [r1:doing{timestamp:4789}]-> (n)"`

Comment: Variable "s" has added,  
`obj.put("query",
    "MATCH (n:activity)\nWHERE n.name=\"" + s
      + "\"\nCREATE (piyumi:Person{name:\"Piyumi\"}) - [r1:doing{timestamp:4789}]-> (n)");`
This should works and gives http status 200